Ubuntu 24.04 server, GRUB seems to ignore gfxmode and gfxpayload
Installed 24.04 in a virtual machine (VirtualBox 6.1, 16MB Video Mem, VGSVGA controller).
In /etc/default/grub:
etc_default_grub
During boot Grub shows the menu in 800x600 resolution, this is what I want.
After making a choice in the menu Ubuntu seems to ignore this setting and increases the size of of the window/console to maximum resolution.
The entry in /etc/grub.d/ for this menu-choice:
etc_grub.d_menuchoice
I like to keep the windows of VM's 800x600, otherwise they don't fit in the host's screen.
Didn't had this problem in 20.04 and 22.04 ...
Something changed?
